# Defining plural form for glossaries entries

Tags: glossaries

Based on the following answer, How shall I define plural form of glossaries?

[Two separate acronym list using package glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126873/two-separate-acronym-list-using-package-glossaries/126889?noredirect=1#comment287540_126889)

For example,

```
\newglossaryentry{LED}
{
  name={LED},
  description={light emitting diode},
  first={\glsentrydesc{LED} (\glsentrytext{LED})},
}
```

The first instance in plural form should print

> light emitting diodes (LEDs).

Second instance of plural form should print

> LEDs

3rd instance of singular form should print

> LED

and so on ...

.

Comment: What about `plural={LEDs},` in your newglossaryentry to be used as `\glsp{LED}`? Not tested but that is the normal way. Maybe you should have a look on acronym lists in the package: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The only way I know is to define the `\newglossaryentry` as:

```
\newglossaryentry{LED}
{
  name={LED},
  description={light emitting diode},
  first={\glsentrydesc{LED} (\glsentrytext{LED})},
  plural={LEDs},
  firstplural={\glsentrydesc{LED}s (\glsentryplural{LED})}
}
```

and then use `\glspl{LED}` when you want the plural form, `\gls{LED}` when you want the singular form.

### EDIT

I've discovered the command `\glsentrydescplural`, which prints the contents of the `descriptionplural` field.

So the above can also be rewritten in a more consistent form as:

```
\newglossaryentry{LED}
{
  name={LED},
  description={light emitting diode},
  first={\glsentrydesc{LED} (\glsentrytext{LED})},
  plural={LEDs},
  descriptionplural={light emitting diodes},
  firstplural={\glsentrydescplural{LED} (\glsentryplural{LED})}
}
```

Comment: Perfect. It takes care of description too.