# Symbol in plural form of acronym in glossaries package

Tags: symbols, glossaries, acronyms

[Follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133150/suppress-symbol-in-nomenclature-after-first-use/133164?noredirect=1#comment301433_133164)

If the plural form acronym is used first then it is printing one `s` after the symbol in parenthesis and this is not desired. For example, if `\glspl{a}` occurs first before any use of `\gls{a}` then it is printing `lattice constants (as)` instead of `lattice constants (a)`.

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that this one is a follow-up to the question [Suppress symbol in nomenclature after first use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133150/suppress-symbol-in-nomenclature-after-first-use), I'll refer to my answer there.

First of all, notice that this is the default behavior, which hasn't been changed by the code in my answer.

Anyway, if you want to change this behavior, substitute the code between `\makeatletter` and `makeatother` in the last part of my answer with the following:

```
\makeatletter

\def\@gls@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\ifx\@glo@type\myacro\glsentrydesc{#2}\else\glsentrytext{#2}\fi}%
          {\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\glsentryfirst{#2}}{\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {\(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
       \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\def\@Gls@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \def\glslabel{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \protected@edef\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\ifx\@glo@type\myacro\glsentrydesc{#2}\else\glsentrytext{#2}\fi}%
          {\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    {%
      \protected@edef\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\glsentryfirst{#2}}{\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{%
      \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
        \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{%
          \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{%
          \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\def\@GLS@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\ifx\@glo@type\myacro\glsentrydesc{#2}\else\glsentrytext{#2}\fi}%
          {\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\glsentryfirst{#2}}{\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
        \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}}{%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\def\@glspl@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\ifx\@glo@type\myacro\glsentrydescplural{#2}\else\glsentryplural{#2}\fi}%
          {\glsentrydescplural{#2}}{\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\ifx\@glo@type\myacro\glsentrydescplural{#2}\space(\glsentrytext{#2})%
           \else\glsentryfirstplural{#2}\fi}%
          {\glsentrydescplural{#2}}{\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
         \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\def\@Glspl@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \def\glslabel{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \protected@edef\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\ifx\@glo@type\myacro\glsentrydescplural{#2}\else\glsentryplural{#2}\fi}%
          {\glsentrydescplural{#2}}{\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    {%
      \protected@edef\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\ifx\@glo@type\myacro\glsentrydescplural{#2}\space(\glsentrytext{#2})%
           \else\glsentryfirstplural{#2}\fi}%
          {\glsentrydescplural{#2}}{\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{%
        \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
        \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{%
          \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{%
          \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\def\@GLSpl@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\ifx\@glo@type\myacro\glsentrydescplural{#2}\else\glsentryplural{#2}\fi}%
          {\glsentrydescplural{#2}}{\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\ifx\@glo@type\myacro\glsentrydescplural{#2}\space(\glsentrytext{#2})%
           \else\glsentryfirstplural{#2}\fi}%
          {\glsentrydescplural{#2}}{\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
        \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\makeatother
```

This should do what you want...

Comment: Of course. Today my internet connection is terrible. And in the mean while I was busy with incorporating your code, checking, along with other nagging corrections in the thesis. :)