# custom plural for the short form of an acronym using glossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using `glossaries` and would like to use a custom short form plural (it should be the same as the short form singular).

I've tried using `\glsshortpluralkey`, but this only affects how the short form plural appears the first time the acronym is used (MWE below). I've also tried using `\glsshortpluralaccess` and `\glsshortplural`, but both are 'undefined control sequences'. I'm using TeX Live 2013.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[\glsshortpluralkey=cM]{cM}{cM}{centiMorgan}

\begin{document}

First use: \glspl{cM}. Second use: \glspl{cM}.

\printglossary[type=acronym,title=List of Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

Edited to clarify: the desired output is:

> First use: centiMorgans (cM). Second use: cM.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In chapter 4 of the [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) the two options are `plural` and `firstplural`.

The change is simply: `\newacronym[plural=cM,firstplural=centiMorgans (cM)]{cM}{cM}{centiMorgan}` and the mwe with this change is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[plural=cM,firstplural=centiMorgans (cM)]{cM}{cM}{centiMorgan}

\begin{document}

First use: \glspl{cM}. Second use: \glspl{cM}.

\printglossary[type=acronym,title=List of Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: mwe result]

Comment: Yes, that works.`\newacronym[plural={cM}, \glsshortpluralkey={cM}]{cM}{cM}{centiMorgan}` is slightly easier.

Comment: @user49858 Only this worked for me, thanks!

Comment: No changes to `\newacronym` worked for me, and I had to resort to a `\newglossaryentry` as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128419/11429 to define "user equipment (UEs)" in "plural".

Comment: Note that this will not work if using `\glsentryfullpl{cM}`. Instead I had to set the long form via `longplural=centriMorgans`, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428266/65754