# Plurals in acronyms when using the glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, plural

I am using the glossaries package for acronyms only, and it is working really well for my document, but I have stumbled upon a problem where it hasn't worked so well.

Literally all but one of my acronyms are work as I intended them to, the one that doesn't work quite how I'd like is one that I sometimes need to use as a plural.

When I use the acronym the first time if I wanted it to be a plural this first time I am using `\glspl{fec}` the problem starts as the acronym already ends in an s for it's full description.

`\newacronym{fec}{FEC}{Forwarding Equivalence Class}`

So when it is used with `\glspl{fec}` it is added another "s" to the end, whereas I would have hoped it would have known to add "es" instead.

Is there a solution to this or should I just reword what I have written to not need the plural variation of the acronym.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To override the default plural forms you can use the `shortplural` key for the short plural and `longplural` for the long plural. These should go in the optional argument:

```
\newacronym
[% options to override defaults
  longplural={Forwarding Equivalence Classes}
]
{fec}{FEC}{Forwarding Equivalence Class}
```