# More than one source of glossaries in one file

Tags: glossaries

I would like to add some glossaries from files. I have got two files of glossaries. I want to add them into my file but not in the same part of my document. When I add them all words are just in one list of words.  But I do not want to get them together. I want to print each content of every file independently.

Thanks for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english, slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}

%---
\makeglossaries
\input{file1.txt}
\input{file2.txt}

\begin{document}

some text

\printglossaries % I want to print words from file file1.txt here.
%\glsaddall

some text

\printglossaries % I want to print words from file file2.txt here.

\end{document}
```

The example of content of files *file1.txt* and *file2.txt*. List of words.

```
 \newglossaryentry{electrics}
 {
 name={electrics},
 description={ rozvod elektriny, elektrina }
 }

 \newglossaryentry{light}
 {
 name={light},
 description={ svetlo $\bullet$ lampa $\bullet$ zapaľovač  },
 plural={lights}
 }
```

Comment: Probably this solution might be of some help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126889/117534. For the code in your question to be more helpful (in making your question more explicit), it would be good to give us examples of what is in `file1` and `file2`.

Comment: @Troy No, the link does not answer my question.

Comment: Why not? Just load them into different glossaries, and print them separately with `printglossary[type=...]` instead of `printglossaries`..

Comment: @Troy Will you show it to me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.txt}% Only to include some sample glossary entries for testing.. Not required in actual code.
     \newglossaryentry{electrics}
    {
        name={electrics},
        description={ rozvod elektriny, elektrina }
    }

    \newglossaryentry{light}
    {
        name={light},
        description={ svetlo $\bullet$ lampa $\bullet$ zapaľovač  },
        plural={lights}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file2.txt}% Only to include some sample glossary entries for testing.. Not required in actual code.
    \newglossaryentry{electrics_2}
    {
        name={electrics},
        description={ rozvod elektriny, elektrina }
    }

    \newglossaryentry{light_2}
    {
        name={light},
        description={ svetlo $\bullet$ lampa $\bullet$ zapaľovač  },
        plural={lights}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english, slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}% Turn off main glossary (if you don't have one)

% Create two new glossaries (so you can customize them to your liking)
\newglossary[nlg]{gloss1}{not}{ntn}{Glossary 1} 
\newglossary[slg]{gloss2}{sot}{stn}{Glossary 2}

\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries[gloss1]{file1.txt} % Load file1 contents into Glossary 1
\loadglsentries[gloss2]{file2.txt} % Load file2 contents into Glossary 2

\begin{document}
\glsaddall % Just to add all glossary entries, for exemplary purposes
some text

\printglossary[type=gloss1] % I want to print words from file file1.txt here.

\clearpage
some text

\printglossary[type=gloss2] % I want to print words from file file2.txt here.

\end{document}
```

page 1:

[image: page1]

page 2:

[image: page 2]

This is essentially the answer given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126889/117534.

Loading the two files into separate glossaries will allow you to print them independently of each other. Note that I used `\printglossary[type=...]` instead of `\printglossaries`. The latter prints *ALL* your glossaries, which is not what you want. The former allows you to specify which glossary to print, at the point you specify in the code.